# How to make an area transparent?

Tags: modeling, transparency

I want to make the black portion in my model transparent so that inside face can be slightly visible. How can i do this?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In **CYCLES** select the mesh you want to be transparent. Go to the ***Object*** header and check the ***Transparency*** box.
[image]

Go to the ***Material*** header, add a new material and decrease the *Alpha* value in the *Settings* panel as pictured below.
[image]

You may also change the color of transparency.
[image]

In **BLENDER INTERNAL** do the same things in ***Object*** header as shown above. Next go to the ***Material*** header, check the ***Transparency*** box and decrease the *Alpha* value in *Transparency* panel.
[image]

---

If your model is one solid mesh (does not consist of many loose meshes) you may add a transparent material to any part of it (any faces) you like.
Create the transparent material (using methods I've shown above) and assign it to the desired faces.
[image]

Here's the result.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With very little information provided, I think you simply need to drop the Alpha on the black Material. If you want complete transparency, and those faces aren't essential, you could just delete them.